# solr scoring for filter query

Tags: solr

I have some fields in my schema as below:

hotel_name:some hotel name

city: some city

county_code: DE

street: some street.

My query to find some hotels looks like this.

```
select/fq=city:"Berlin"&fq=country_code"DE"&fq=hotel_name:"achat berlin hotel"=city:"Berlin"&fq=country_code"DE"&fq=hotel_name:"achat berlin hotel"
```

Return values, cotains lots of hotels found with some or more token machted in hotel_name field. If i want to short, these documents per number of the token matched in hotel_name files, how can i do that. I would like to keep maximum number of matched token in hotel_name field at the top.

E.G. if hotel name cotain all three tokens : achat, berlin and hotel, it should appear at the top. and lower match should appear below.

Is it possible to score a document depending of the number of the token matched per field.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first off, your query is badly formed. You need to start the query with a `?`, provided a `q` parameter, provide a `:` between the `country_code` field name and the value, and you don't need to repeat the `fq` parameters. It should be:

```
?q=*:*&fq=city:"Berlin"&fq=country_code:"DE"&fq=hotel_name:"achat berlin hotel"
```

The `hotel_name`, `country_code`, and `city` these `fq` parameters will be tokenized and analyzed according to your `schema.xml` and may match exactly or not depending on the query slop you specified in `solrconfig.xml`.

> Is it possible to score a document depending of the number of the
>   token matched per field.

The scoring in solr isn't this literal, so no, not exactly.

> E.G. if hotel name cotain all three tokens : achat, berlin and hotel,
>   it should appear at the top. and lower match should appear below.

You've provided the query as a phrase (it's quoted with `"`s), so solr will by default find that exact phrase, and give it an associated score. If [query slop](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#qs_.28Query_Phrase_Slop.29) (the `qs` parameter) is configured in your `solrconfig.xml`, then a score from a sloppy query will also be added. What you probably really want is:

```
hotel_name:achat berlin hotel
```

Which is a non-phrase query.

Answer (score 0):

What is the  type of the field "hotel_name" in the schema.xml?

Also, have you tried it already? By default Solr takes into account the coordination factor:

"if there are multiple terms in a query, the more terms that match, the higher the score". So, I guess that it's already happening in your case.

Comment: it does not happen automatically. Sometimes i am getting documents with less match, ahead then more match. hotel_name is of type: